# User lacks the rights to filter based on campaign name in a related report

Tags: user-management, profile, reporting

There is a particular issue that is stumping me at the moment. 
We have a custom report type that is of the type Campaigns with Opportunities.  We have a report in our org that uses a filter based on a field on the Campaign (Campaign Name).
One of our users cannot filter based on that field, so that when he sees the report it shows all opportunities from the beginning of time. In fact, when I log myself in as him and try to edit that report, he cannot filter on any campaign fields at all.
The user is:
A Marketing User
has 'Create & Customize Reports' and 'Manage Public Reports' rights.
has read, create & edit rights on Campaigns, and has both read & edit rights on the Campaign Name field according to his profile.

This is just probably something that is eluding me at the moment, based on how Salesforce manages Campaigns & Reports (like how you must really be a marketing user to work with these items, even though you have nothing to do with Marketing at all.  Idiosyncrasies :)

Any ideas on what might be wrongly set up?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible conditions that would cause this to happen:

1. The user must have a Marketing User profile (which you said is true).
2. The user's detail page must have Marketing User checked (which assigns the actual marketing license).
3. The field(s) in question must be visible to the user (Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Fields > Campaign > Set Field Level Security...).

The second step is the most often overlooked, since one tends to assume that assigning a profile with those permissions is sufficient.